# Specifying different database addresses in project.clj

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a Leiningen Clojure project which specifies a Postgres database in `project.clj` like this:

```
:profiles {:test {:env {:db-address "//non-standard/location" ...} ...} ...}
```

Now I'm trying to run my tests on a machine where the database is in a standard location, and I can't figure out how to run my tests in a way that respects this location.

I've added an additional profile entry:

```
:other {:env {:db-address "//standard/location"}}}
```

...and then run `lein with-profile other test`, thinking that just the `:db-address` entry would override the one in `:test`, but I still get `Connection refused`.

I've duplicated the `:test` entry entirely in `:other` except that I change the `:db-address` entry only, but that doesn't have any effect, whether I run `lein with-profile other test` or `lein with-profile +other test`.

If I then delete the `:test` profile entirely, leiningen fails completely, even though the docs say that `lein with-profile other test` should ignore the other profiles.

I'm pretty much stumped.  I can run my tests if I textually replace the non-standard location with the standard location in `project.clj` before running `lein`, but I'm hoping for something more official and less hacky.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDITED TO ADD:

I tried using the `^:replace` tag in two ways.

```
:other {:env {:db-address ^:replace "//standard/location" } }
```

This causes an error `Metadata can only be applied to IMetas`.

```
:other {:env ^:replace { ... map copied from :test profile ... } }
```

This causes an error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate ring/mock/request__init.class or ring/mock/request.clj on classpath: , compiling [...]`.  So apparently my CLASSPATH gets nuked in this case?  Baffling.

EDITED FURTHER TO ADD:

The "empty classpath" error just above was apparently due to a `:dependencies` parameter in the `:test` profile I wasn't carrying over to the `:other` profile.

Comment: This should work. I can think of some reasons it doesn't. Have you tried using `^replace` in your `:other` profile like this `:db-address ^:replace "//some-location"` or even better on the whole `:env` key. Have you print debugged the value of `:db-address` on startup? Do you have an environment variable DB_ADDRESS which could override the one from your project.clj?

Comment: That should work. The only thing I can think of is that both profile are being loaded and `test` is overriding `other`. Try Kungi's suggestion or alternatively this: `lein with-profile -test,+other test`

Comment: Ah yes, I tried using the `:^replace` tag, just forgot to mention it.  See above for added details.

Comment: Kungi: Your comment basically got me past the problem.  If you post it as an official answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'd create an additional profile for standard location and simply run `lein with-profile +standard-test test` for tests with standard db location and `lein with-profile +other-test test` for the other one. Moreover, you can create aliases for both cases like `{:aliases {"test" ["with-profile" "+standard-test" "test"] "test-other" ["with-profile" "+other-test" "test"] } }`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it better to not keep this information directly in my project.clj file. Instead, I use [environ](https://github.com/weavejester/environ), which will allow you to either use shell environment variables or a environment profile file - you can have different ones for each environment.

The benefit with doing this is then you don't have any worries about possibly pushing sensitive database details into version control and you get a simpler project.clj (IMO) setup. I don't put my environment profile file into version control and I find it easy to manage deployments using a combination of environment profile files and normal shell environments (which sys admins who may not be familiar with clojure are very comfortable with)